# R CRAN repositories not available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, cran

I just installed Ubuntu LTS 18.04 *Bionic Beaver* and I want to install R and R Studio. If I look at the URL below I notice there's no repository (yet) for *Bionic Beaver*. The newest repository is *Artful Aardvark*.

https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Typically how long will it take for the CRAN mirrors to get updated? Ubuntu 18.04 was released several weeks ago. Obviously, the command below does not currently work on my system.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cran.mtu.edu//bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/ bionic-backports main restricted universe"
```

Is there another way to activate the backports repository?

Comment: See the r-sig-debian list for more.